Keycloak permissions in JWT
Is it possible to add scope based permissions to JWT?
Something like this:
{
  "my-client": {
    "roles": [
      "SUPER_ADMIN"
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "create",
      "update"
    ]
  }
}

I've added Authorization scope "create" with associated permission "create" and created policy in which SUPER_ADMIN role is added.
